# Make/trick Visual C++ into indenting macros structure properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Consider these macros

```
#define BEGIN(Parent) void Process(){

#define ELEMENT(Elem) RegisterElement(Elem);

#define END }
```

When using them, Visual Studio will not recognize `ELEMENT` as part of a child code block and thus not indent it properly

```
BEGIN(ParentClass)   <--- hit ENTER here and carret will go below `B` in begin, with no indentation
ELEMENT(m_member)
END
```

Is there a way to trick Visual Studio, as in a way I could code my macros or maybe some helpful pragmas so that Visual Studio recognizes the opening and closing scope of `RegisterElement` function and thus indend `ELEMENT` entries properly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Code alignment extension for VS 2013/12/10

Here's url: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd

From Edit->Code Alignment menu, select 'Align from caret'

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping of a solution not involving plugins, since I'm not the only one working on this project. Other people will use these macros as well, and requiring them to install a plugin just for this is a bit too much.

Comment: Visual studio at this stage doesn't have built-in support to align pre-processor directives. plugins or third party tools such as Astyle are only options for you.